# How do I get div columns to line up?

Tags: css

[image][image: New pic after flex][image: Screen Shot]I've tried relative and absolute positioning.  I'm not seeing something correctly.

It continues to look like this. I don't want to use fixed although I have made that work, the page won't scroll.

Here's some CSS for the current situation (There's a header above and that's why the top margin is 250.):

Wrapper:

```
    .container_Wrapper{
        position:absolute;
    }
```

Column 1:

```
    .dateSelector {
        margin-top: 250px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        width: 350px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 350px;
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
```

Column 2:

```
    .DSP_Reports {
        margin-top: 250px;
        margin-left: 350px;
        /*margin: 0;*/
        padding: 0;
        width: 350px;
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        float:none;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the flex-box to resolve your problems. I have a demo for you

Wrapper

```
.container_Wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Column 1:

```
.dateSelector {
   width: 300px;
}
```

Column 2:

```
.DSP_Reports {
   width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Yes.  I was working with the previous answer-er and he assisted.  My second picture had margins.  Your answer worked. Thanks!